# Why is $Z(G) = \ker(Ad)$?

Tags: group-theory

Define the map $Ad(g)(h) = ghg^{-1}$, so this is just self conjugation map.

I get that for $h \in \ker(Ad(g)(h)) \iff ghg^{-1}=e_G \iff gh = g \iff h = e_G.$

I am reading other proofs and they reduced $ghg^{-1}=e_G$ to $ghg^{-1}=h \iff gh = hg $ for every $h \in G$ to get the center of the group. Sorry, but how did the identity become $h$?

Comment: You are mixing the kernel of $Ad$, which is what you want to find, with the kernel of $Ad(g)$ for some $g\in G$, which is always trivial, with the kernel of $Ad(g)(h)$, which simply does not make any sense.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, $Ad(g)(h)$ does not make sense because I have already selected $h$. Which is an element of the $Im(gxg^{-1})$, so it cannot have a kernel?

Comment: Ad(g)(h) **does** make sense,bot not talking about is kernel.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, sorry that's what I mean because $Ad(g)(h) \in Im(gxg^{-1})$

Answer (score 1):

$Ad$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to the automorphism group of $G$. In other words $Ad(g)\in Aut(G)$.

So $\text{Ker} Ad$ is the set of elements $g\in G$ such that $Ad(g)$ is the identity.

So $g\in \text{Ker} Ad \Rightarrow\forall h\in G,\,\,Ad(g)(h)=h$ and this means $g\in \text{Ker} Ad\Rightarrow \forall h\in G,\,\, ghg^{-1}=h$.

And so $g$ commutes with all the elements of $G$. And therefore $\text{Ker} Ad\subset Z(G)$.

Conversely any $g\in Z(G)$ is such that $Ad(g)=Id$

Comment: So $Ad$ is the map, but $Ad(g)$ is the image of $g$ under $Ad$. Such an image is given by the conjugation? And by identity, you mean $I(g) = g$

Comment: $Ad$ is a map from $G$ to $Aut(G)$ while $Ad(g)$ is an inner automorphism from $G$ to $G$. Identity is as you describe it